# Mongoose, how do I sort this by id and descending?

Tags: express, mongoose

I have this code: and i want it to sort the musics through id and list it by desc so every time a user post the latest post is on the top.

```
router.get('/getAllMusic', (req, res) => {
    Music.find({}, (err, musics) => {
        if (err) {
            res.json({ success: false, message: err });
        }

        else if (!musics) {
            res.json({ success: false, message: musics});
        }

        else {
            res.json({ success: true, musics: musics});
        }
    }).sort({ '_id': -1 });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have the date field in recode use that for sorting,

Because _id will not return the expected result. It does not sort only by timestamp, It's a combination of multiple parameters. [Refer this](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/)

**The 12-byte ObjectId value consists of:**

> a 4-byte value representing the seconds since the Unix epoch(timestamp),
>
> a 3-byte machine identifier,
>
> a 2-byte process id, and
>
> a 3-byte counter, starting with a random value.